# Event handler for web fonts load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a piece of code that wants to perform a jump to a particular id on the page as soon as the page is ready. I accomplish this by performing a `jquery.animate()` so that the `scrollTop` is at my target element.

However, I'm using web fonts, and for some reason the `ready` event is firing *before* the web fonts have loaded and been applied. The result is that the animation ends on a position that is often completely unrelated to the actual position of the element I want to scroll to.

I've verified this by opening the timeline in the Chrome inspector, where I see the animation triggering, followed by the web font loading, followed by a re-render which causes my animation target scroll point to become meaningless. I've also confirmed that this issue does not manifest itself when I use a system font.

Could anyone offer some advice? Perhaps there's some sort of event that fires after a web font has been applied?

Comment: The answers below are correct. Another time you want to use the window.load event is for images. If you are making any sort of calculation on image dimensions, you should wait for window.load or else the dimensions supplied could be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).ready(...)` is triggered when the browser has finished downloading the entire **HTML** of the page.  It is often before the browser has finished downloading the stylesheets, let alone the font files.

---

Assuming it's loaded from a stylesheet included in the HTML (as opposed to a JavaScript added stylesheet), you should be listening for the window event, rather than the document's load event.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    // your resources are loaded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .load instead, as .ready is only after the DOM is loaded.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```

Here is info regarding why .ready() is NOT what you want:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Here is info why .load() (really the Javascript load event) is what you want (it waits for resources to be loaded): 
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/